# Color Ramp not working in shading mode in blender 3.3

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to texture lips, in blender 3.3, by following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/PjvwaC3ql0U

When I apply the color ramp it should spread the colors like in the image 1 but i'm getting a full color like in image 2 instead.

How can i solve that?

Thank you.
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Edited:

I've added the model file, you can download it from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6bsboecds6xy0qe/Model_Blender3.3.rar?dl=0

Edited 2:

 Video what I'm doing: [www.dropbox.com/s/yazl7o04uvrg8pa/colorRamp%20blender%203.3.mp4?dl=0](http://www.dropbox.com/s/yazl7o04uvrg8pa/colorRamp%20blender%203.3.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx, but did u see the difference in gradient texture? linear <> quadratic sphere, maybe this already helps

Comment: I've tried with all the parameters but nothing happens. I also use the alpha node in the colorRamp instead of the color node but nothings happens. 
I've uploaded the model file.

Comment: Well, from your image, you try to use object from the texture coordinate node instead of U, move everything to 0 location on the mapping node and make it smaller also on the mapping node

Comment: @Emir: Please see my answer

Comment: Instead of using the 'UV' output of _Texture Coordinate_, Use a _UV Map_ input node, set to UVMap.001. At least, then, you're referencing the right UV  map. And use a 'Quad Sphere' _Gradient_ instead of 'Linear', for a result analogous to your working reference. But really, I think you might be better off rethinking your mapping altogether.

Comment: @RobinBetts I use your settings and I got what you see in the video i uploaded. why do you say i have to rethink my mapping?

Comment: Charly  ... I guess it depends on exactly what you're looking for.. I was thinking graduations of color across lips alone, isolated from surrounding skin. Typically the mask for that would be a painted  / an image, not an attempt to make procedural shapes fit. But I may be barking up completely the wrong tree.. :)

Comment: @RobinBetts and how can I accomplish what I want to do. Did you see the video I uploaded? I almost done, I only need to rotate of 90° the degradation colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have selected the wrong uv map, select the second one here:

[image]

after selecting the right uv map you have to change the size of the UV editing as well, as you already see in your own posted picture.

So select all vertices and press S Y and move your mouse

Like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new in blender. How do you select it? I thought that just by clicking on it it'll be automatically selected.
does it work for you?

Comment: I already selected the UV Map but nothing happens.

Comment: in the file you uploaded your uvmap is selected. With that it doesnt work. You see which one is selected by the white camera symbol -> you should select UVMap.001....if this still doesn't work with (!) the gradient change i told you before, pls make a video and show us what you have done, because i think you didn't make all the changes. you can link the video either in the comments or in the question.

Comment: another hint to tutorials: If you are a beginner, you should try to follow EXACTLY how the tutorials works. Don't make any difference especially if you are a beginner. Just as example: your uv editing a lot smaller than in the tutorial. And often it's the little things which make a huge difference in Blender. It is seldom just "one click" and it works. So you might as well have to change the UV editing a bit and play around with the colorramp. But with select the right uvmap and selecting quadratic sphere you should get at least a drastic improvement so that it looks more like the tutorial.

Comment: and if you look exactly at the tutorial: he resizes the uv's so that the mouth is all over the UV editing space. You didn't do that at all....

Comment: I was following the tutorial and I also resize the uv map making it small and large but i got stuck in the colorRamp think. 
Now I've applied the settings of Robin Betts and i have an improvement. Please check out the next video. How can I rotate the gradient colors? 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yazl7o04uvrg8pa/colorRamp%20blender%203.3.mp4?dl=0

Comment: i updated my answer. I can just repeat: watch the tutorials carefully and repeat *every little* step they made. You didn't do that at all. Neither with the uv map - nor with the scaling. It is the best if watch it again and again and do all the things - by this you will learn the most.

Comment: ...and no, you don't have to change the UV output as Robin said, just selecting the right UV map works. I tried that out. Of course Robins solution "works" too, but it is not necessary. It works how i wrote it.

Comment: and another hint: you shouldn't follow very short tutorials who aren't really suitable for beginners and which don't explain what keys were pressed and don't explain exactly why what happens. You should watch beginner tutorials about UV editing and shading like e.g. from Grant Abitt... You see how you are struggling here..."normally" more subscribers > 10K means: better tutorials.

Comment: So did you do with my model what they do in the tutorial and it worked for you? Can you please share it. I did what you said, I followed then the tutorial step by step and nothing changed for me. Thanks

Comment: yes, just one min

Comment: here you can download: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ikh34m996bzov23/Man_Modeled_repaired.blend?dl=0

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help.  One more question: How can I show the UV map at the left of the screen as you do? I activated the UV map window but it is empty.

Comment: you have to select your mesh vertices/faces on your model on the right side, then the corresponding uv-vertices will be selected like this:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bYMg.gif

Comment: Please Charly, don't ask more questions in comments because other people cannot find these questions and answer in the comments. This site has the sense to help other people as well, not just the one who asks. So all user can learn from other people answers. But if you ask in comments, nobody can learn from it. So just open another question - you may ask as many questions as you like. There is no limit.